# Better "Close Question" workflow for non-programming questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vote-to-close, close-reasons

The workflow for voting to close a question that is basically tech support for a product (particularly a Linux flavor) is currently lacking because it requires the user to come up with a custom close reason more than half the time, in my experience. I would like for this to change, because closing questions is hard enough as it is.

### Examples

- The [Kali Linux tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux) is notorious for tech support questions. Here are three "Why isn't my wireless card working?" questions:  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201231/how-to-use-the-bcm2837-on-kali-linux) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152324/kali-linux-wireless-not-working) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086360/usb-wifi-dongle-not-working-in-virtual-box)
- It's not just Kali Linux, though. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230781/touchpad-becames-disabled-in-linux-after-windows-booting-in-dual-boot) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224751/i-am-trying-to-port-forward-but-no-matter-what-i-do-it-wont-work)
- Questions that should be directed to support for a product that we probably can't even answer. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39211367/2588818) (note that, to my knowledge, [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) does not list Stack Overflow as a source of tech support, like some other products do).

I didn't even have to search for these. They're on the first page of recent questions for tags I follow.

### Reasons the current close reasons are unsatisfactory

- This belongs on the *X Stack Exchange* site

A lot of times Stack Overflowers are not active on these sites and do not actually know what is on-topic there. This causes problems when we say, "Just go to *[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)*" or "Just go to *[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)*" or "Just go to *[Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)*", because then we create issues for them, or their users come back to SO to flame us in comments for the bad recommendation.

There's also a split between what sites we can recommend and not, I guess because of what automatic migration processes exist. For instance, I believe a lot of the Linux questions might be welcome at *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)*, but I can't choose it.

- Duplicate / too broad / unclear / opinion-based

These usually do not apply, or at least they don't often enough to help. I could sarcastically use "Why isn't this code working?" or "cannot reproduce" since they don't have any code, I guess...

---

I would like to see a simple canned message for questions that in no way follow the guidelines in the help center. We are not tech support or a code-writing service, but the users having to explain this all day and every day don’t get any help from the UI.

I have tagged this as discussion at the moment because without a concrete proposal (e.g., wording) I feel it is not a proper feature request. I would like community feedback first and then this can either become a feature request or we can make a new question.

Comment: Get my Always Be Closing script over on stack apps.  The OT button votes to close as off topic with a custom comment "This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center."

Comment: My workflow is: close -> off topic -> reason #1. Why isn't this acceptable? Because it mentions Super User? I've seen *very* few people follow that advice and dump their question on Super User. If these were people who read help and guidelines, they wouldn't be posting their question on the wrong site in the first place. That said, we do need a better workflow, one that doesn't require so many eyes and hands to dispatch *obviously* off-topic questions.

Comment: @CodyGray I was lumping that and the next one (which mentions "Server Fault") under "This belongs on X.StackExchange". I am not active on Super User or Server Fault so I don't know what's on topic there or what's not, and I don't want them to have to deal with BS Linux Tech support questions if they don't want to or have to either.

Comment: I have a bunch of stock comments which I copy, paste, & modify as appropriate.  For custom closure, I'm thinking of using something like: "**This question is off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)**"

Comment: FWIW, plenty of Kali Linux questions _do_ get asked on U&L, but I don't think I've _ever_ seen one there that wasn't close-worthy.

Comment: "Just go to Programmers" I'm active there too but I never say it like this. I always say: "This is not good for StackOverflow because XX but it might be something for Programmers.StackExchange". Never did anyone complain.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm not talking about that particular wording (which I would never use either) so much as the recommendation in and of itself leading to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl). Interestingly the top comment on that Meta question links to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51663/off-topic-questions-being-moved-to-super-user) describing the same with regards to Super User, which is back to the reason I was ignoring Close Reason #1.

Comment: @Will It doesn't comment for me. But I love your script, using it for quite some time!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I think the best would be a two step process where the target site has to accept a question as ontopic before it is migrated or the OP does it himself. But then on the other hand I think I am fairly good at identifying questions that could be migrated (at least when also being active on the target site).

Comment: @Trilarion I'd support that feature request!

Comment: @baao the comment is part of the post payload.  Not sure what they do with it server side...

Comment: [Referenced on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383166/is-topic-hostile-downvoting-a-thing-and-are-se-algorithms-designed-to-catch-it/383189#383189) (2022-10-25).

Comment: I'm marking this completed, because 1) the most-upvoted was previously done, and 2) it's now been adapted into an even more general reason that covers that and more.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Reasons the Current Close Reasons are Unsatisfactory

What about the obvious close reason:

> Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

That's not the same as migrating to another Stack. The fact that it mentions Super User is essentially incidental. The main point is the part that's bold-face.

Comment: I didn't see it as incidental until your answer and CodyGray's comment. I was lumping that under essentially a migration reason, same as the "Server Fault" one.

Comment: I think this reason reads as "migrate to Super User." Some improved phrasing might be helpful.

Comment: Note that there *is* a "migrate to Super User" option, @ssube. Close -> off-topic -> "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" -> Super User. This is different from the reason that Nicol mentions here.

Comment: Why even mention Super User then? I came to the exact conclusion as @ssube.

Comment: @Jacob: Because such questions could be on topic for that site. Why are you so focused on the last sentence rather than the first sentence with the **bold face text** that explicitly emphasizes the **important information**?

Comment: Just because that's the most important information doesn't mean the rest isn't important. I'm a programmer, so I read into "what does this actually mean" for messages, in other words, "what will happen?" My assumption that migration to superuser is what happens was incorrect. To me, it's weird that superuser would be mentioned but migration wouldn't automatically occur, that we'd expect the user to copy/paste their question.

Comment: Also of note, Super User, and Server Fault are mentioned, and there's another option that says "belongs to another site in the Stack Exchange network," which to me implies that option 1 is for migrating to Super User, option 2 is for migrating to Server Fault, and option 6 is for migrating to other locations. I would not expect that Super User would be in option 6 because option 1 already mentions that other stack exchange site.

Comment: @Jacob: "*To me, it's weird that superuser would be mentioned but migration wouldn't automatically occur, that we'd expect the user to copy/paste their question.*" We don't expect the user to copy&paste their question. We expect the user to go to that site and determine if their question is appropriate for it. Again, the important part is that questions of that sort don't belong *here*; that we direct them to where such questions *might* be appropriate is merely being helpful. Migration is a separate option because it *explicitly causes* migration of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I find that the three first reasons for closing off-topic questions could do the job quite well:

[image]

> **This belongs on the** ***X Stack Exchange*** **site**
> A lot of times Stack Overflowers are not active on these sites and do not actually know what is on-topic there. This causes problems when we say, "Just go to *Software Engineering*" or "Just go to *Code Review*" or "Just go to *Super User*" because then we create issues for them, or there users come back to SO to flame us in comments for the bad recommendation.

Use the recommendations for Super User or Server Fault only when you feel the question would be on topic there.

> There's also a split between what sites we can recommend and not, I guess because of what automatic migration processes exist. For instance, I believe a lot of the Linux questions might be welcome at *Unix & Linux*, but I can't choose it.

I think another Meta question, one specifically asking to add a link to the Linux Stack Exchange sites in the "it belongs somewhere else section", would not hurt.

Comment: I like most of this, but your response to "This belongs on X.StackExchange" missed what I saw as OP's main point, which was that many SO users (explicitly including OP) don't know what's on-topic there. Your response covers the "I know that I don't know" possibility, but you gloss over the problem of an SO reviewer thinking they know what's on-topic there but being wrong. I've seen enough meta posts about migration to know that that's actually a frequent occurrence at scale, assuming the good intentions of SO reviewers.